# Text Rendering iOS - Most performant way to render fast changing text

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, nsattributedstring, core-text

What is the most performant way to render fast changing text (10-15 numbers that change every single frame) in iOS?  Those are the tries that I did so far:

1) `CATextLayer` + `CTFont` and `NSString`: Quite fast but no access to kerning, which I need. (If somebody knows a trick how to get kerning to work with `CTFont` and without `NSAttributedString`, that'd also be cool, but it's not the main question ;)  )

2) `CATextLayer` + `NSAttributedString`: Slow and laggy. I see huge FPS drops compared to 1). In my app this change lets the FPS drop from 50-60 to 30.

3) Bitmap Fonts, using `UIImageViews` and `UIImage` to display the numbers: Quite fast as well, though not really satisfying as there should be a better way / a more natural way in iOS to render fonts efficiently.

EDIT:

4) `UILabel` + `NSString` - Quite Fast, but again no access to kerning.

5) `UILabel` + `NSAttributedString` - Slow and laggy again.

Rendering an `NSAttributedString` is a lot slower than rendering a basic `NSString`. This is really frustrating as all I need from `NSAttributedString` at the moment is the spacing between letters.

Comment: a great performance-oriented question.  BTW did you simply try a UILabel, to see what the apple engineers have done?

Comment: Thank you, I just tried it (edited into question), and it's quite fast as long as you don't use attributedText, which I need for changing the kerning.

Comment: Maybe try Sprite Kit with a single texture of your fonts for an even faster bitmap blitting of your image based fonts - assuming Sprite Kit batches those draw calls and is good at this. SKView to the.... textscue.

Comment: Have you tried using a `CFAttributedString` to apply kerning with `CTFont` ?

Answer (score 0):

Apple added TextKit to iOS recently, you might start by checking this: [TextKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html).